# Failed to resolve org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.7.2

Tags: junit, junit-vintage

I have this error qhen i try tu run the Junit Test of a project.
But it  only happen with one module that doesn't have any difference with the junit dependencies.
On the other hand, my workmate can run the test of this module without problems, so i asume that is something in my IDE with this.
I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3

Anyone had this problem before or have any idea about where to see to solve it?
Thank you all!

I tried to clean the cache, reload the project from git and with the version of intllij that my workmate has, but nothing worked.